# How to center items in a Recyclerview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using RecyclerView with Cardview items inside it. I set the  GridLayoutManager to show 2 items at each row and I want it to be centered on all phones like this :

**expected result**

[image: expected result]

But I have currently these :

**Actual result**

[image: actual result]

I tried different poor solutions (paddingLeft...) but it works on phones with bigger screens and doesn't work on smaller phones.

content_main.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:queryHint="Rechercher un film"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movies_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

movie_card.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="170dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_movie_poster"
            android:layout_width="170dip"
            android:layout_height="256dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/movie_image_description"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_movie_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_movie_poster"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And app_bar_main.xml which includes the content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `GridLayoutManager` set `card_view.xml` parent view width as `match_parent` i.e.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" //change
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"//add this
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Or you can make that `RelativeLayout` and set child `CardView` `centerInParent` to `true`

Comment in case of any queries

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

set right or left margin in your recyler view :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movies_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `movie_card.xml` set width to `match_parent` and add gravity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" //<-- change
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" //<-- add
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. You need to remove `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` and add 
        `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:queryHint="Rechercher un film"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movies_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope that will works for you.